# Why does this application include a private RSA key?

Tags: tls, rsa

I downloaded an application, based on electron. I then decompiled the app.asar file. And I found two strange files: "server.cert" and "server.key".
The private RSA key corresponds to the certificate.

I was wondering what this could be used for. Have any developers forgotten their key? Or is it for SSL encryption? But in that case, why include the private RSA key?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try opening server.crt.  What does it show in the SAN (or common name) field?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Both of the files should be human readable and often have some useful info for you

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, it is hard to conclusively say what the purpose of this key is. Examining the certificate can provide more information about the purpose of the certificate and the corresponding key.

It could be that it is the server certificate. In that case, having access to the private key makes it possible to present your server as the application's server, and perform a man-in-the-middle attack. In some cases it is also possible to revoke the certificate, making it invalid even for the original web server.

It could be a client certificate. TLS allows mutual authentication, where both the server and client present a certificate. This application could have enabled this to enforce that only the official application can communicate with the server. However, it is necessary to include the private key in the application, making it possible to extract it. You can check whether the server requires client authentication by performing a request with another client. If the TLS connection fails, the server likely requires a certificate. Now that you have the private key, you can perform requests with another application. The impact of this is probably limited, as this won't be the only access control that the application has.

The certificate could also be for something else, or serve no purpose at all. It is hard to say without more information.